# Trying to return 60,000 information to Datatables Jquery - VB.NET and JQuery

Tags: jquery, .net, vb.net, datatables

Been trying for a while to display a big set of data to my datatable but the only thing I get its a crash or a timeout on the browser.

My return data is correct because with less than 1000 records the table is correctly load.

This is what my table displays
[image: blank table]

This is my current code

Js

```
var exampleTable = $('#example').DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "responsive": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "EmailService.asmx/exampleScript",
            "type": "GET",
            "contentType": "application/json",
            "dataType": "json",
            "dataSrc": function (json) {
             //console.log(json.d);
                var output = JSON.parse(json.d);
    
                json.draw = output.Draw;
                json.recordsTotal = output.recordsTotal;
                json.recordsFiltered = output.recordsFiltered;

                return output.data;
               

            },
        },
        scrollY: 500,
        deferRender: true,
        scroller: true,
        "pageLength": 50,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Progress" },
            { "data": "Status" },
            { "data": "Mail" },
            { "data": "Date_Delivery" },
            { "data": "Date_Send" },
            { "data": "Date_Reject" },
            { "data": "Date_Open" },
            { "data": "Date_First_Click" },
            { "data": "Date_Last_Click" },
            { "data": "Date_Bounce" },
            { "data": "Date_Complaint" },
            { "data": "Date_Delivery_Delay" },
            { "data": "Date_Bounce_Type" },
            { "data": "Date_Bounce_Sub_Type" },
            { "data": "ErrorDescription" }
        ]
    });
```

VB.NET - Controller

```
 <WebMethod>
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=True)>
Public Function exampleScript()
    Dim defaultDatabaseEngine = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DATABASE_ENGINE_DEFAULT")
    Dim CS As String = ""
    If defaultDatabaseEngine.Equals("MySQL") Then
        CS = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MySQLConnString").ConnectionString.ToString()
    ElseIf defaultDatabaseEngine.Equals("MSSQL") Then
        CS = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MSSQLConnString").ConnectionString.ToString()
    End If

    Dim dataset As New DataSet()
    Dim tableprincipal As New StringBuilder()
    'Dim n_Metadados As String = ""

    Dim stringQuery = "SELECT OCP_MAILS.DESTINATION as Mail , OCP_MAILS.MESSAGE_ID as MessageID , OCP_MAILS.EVENT_DELIVERY as Date_Delivery , OCP_MAILS.EVENT_SEND as Date_Send, OCP_MAILS.EVENT_REJECT as Date_Reject ,
        (SELECT TOP 1 OCP_MAIL_OPENS.TIMESTAMP FROM OCP_MAIL_OPENS WHERE OCP_MAILS.HDR = '2021001109' AND OCP_MAIL_OPENS.MESSAGE_ID = OCP_MAILS.MESSAGE_ID) As Date_Open,
        (SELECT TOP 1(OCP_MAIL_LINKS_CLICKED.TIMESTAMP)  FROM OCP_MAIL_LINKS_CLICKED WHERE OCP_MAILS.HDR = '2021001109' AND OCP_MAIL_LINKS_CLICKED.MESSAGE_ID = OCP_MAILS.MESSAGE_ID) as Date_First_Click,
        (SELECT TOP 1(OCP_MAIL_LINKS_CLICKED.TIMESTAMP)  FROM OCP_MAIL_LINKS_CLICKED  WHERE OCP_MAILS.HDR = '2021001109' AND OCP_MAIL_LINKS_CLICKED.MESSAGE_ID = OCP_MAILS.MESSAGE_ID ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC) as Date_Last_Click,
     OCP_MAILS.EVENT_BOUNCE as Date_Bounce , OCP_MAILS.EVENT_COMPLAINT as Date_Complaint , OCP_MAILS.EVENT_DELIVERYDELAY as Date_Delivery_Delay , OCP_MAILS.EVENT_BOUNCE_TYPE as Date_Bounce_Type , 
         OCP_MAILS.EVENT_BOUNCE_SUBTYPE as Date_Bounce_SubType
        FROM OCP_MAILS WHERE OCP_MAILS.HDR = '2021001109'"

    Dim jsonstring As String
    Dim jobCounter = 0
    Dim Informacoes As New List(Of info)


    Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(CS)
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(stringQuery, con)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        con.Open()
        Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        


        'Dim mailProgress As JobSelectedProgress = New JobSelectedProgress()
        While rdr.Read()

            Dim ProgressString As String
            Dim StatusString As String

            If rdr("Date_First_Click").ToString <> "" Then
                ProgressString = "<th scope='row'><div class='progress' style='height:10px;'><div class='progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-success progress-bar-animated' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='100' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width:100%'></div></div></th>"
                StatusString = ("<span class='status-p bg-success'>Clicked</span>")

            ElseIf rdr("Date_Open").ToString <> "" Then
                ProgressString = ("<th scope='row'><div class='progress' style='height:10px;'><div class='progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-warning progress-bar-animated' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='75' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width:75%'></div></div></th>")
                StatusString = ("<span class='status-p bg-warning'>Opened</span>")

            ElseIf rdr("Date_Delivery").ToString <> "" Then
                ProgressString = ("<th scope='row'><div class='progress' style='height:10px;'><div class='progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-info progress-bar-animated' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='50' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width:50%'></div></div></th>")
                StatusString = ("<span class='status-p bg-info'>Delivery</span>")

            ElseIf (rdr("Date_Send").ToString <> "" And Not rdr("Date_Bounce").ToString <> "") Then
                ProgressString = ("<th scope='row'><div class='progress' style='height:10px;'><div class='progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-secondary progress-bar-animated' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='25' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width:25%'></div></div></th>")
                StatusString = ("<span class='status-p bg-secondary'>Sent</span>")

            Else
                ProgressString = ("<th scope='row'><div class='progress' style='height:10px;'><div class='progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-primary progress-bar-animated' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='10' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width:10%'></div></div></th>")
                StatusString = ("<span class='status-p bg-primary'>KO</span>")

            End If

            Dim errorDescriptionString As String

            If (rdr("Date_Bounce_Type").ToString.Equals("Permanent") And rdr("Date_Bounce_SubType").ToString.Equals("General")) Or (rdr("Date_Bounce_SubType").ToString.Contains("smtp;550 5.5.0")) Or (rdr("Date_Bounce_SubType").ToString.Contains("invalid_domain")) Then
                errorDescriptionString = ("Dominio Erroneo")

            ElseIf (rdr("Date_Bounce_SubType").ToString.Contains("Undetermined")) Or (rdr("Date_Bounce_Type").ToString.Contains("Transient") And rdr("Date_Bounce_SubType").ToString.Contains("General")) Then
                errorDescriptionString = ("Indeterminado")

            ElseIf (rdr("Date_Bounce_SubType").ToString.Contains("MailboxFull")) Then
                errorDescriptionString = ("Buzon de Correo lleno")

            ElseIf (rdr("Date_Bounce_SubType").ToString.Contains("ContentRejected")) Then
                errorDescriptionString = ("Contenido Del Mensaje Rechazado")

            ElseIf (rdr("Date_Bounce_SubType").ToString.Contains("Suppressed")) Then
                errorDescriptionString = ("Spam")

            ElseIf (rdr("Date_Bounce_SubType").ToString.Contains("OnAccountSuppressionList")) Then
                errorDescriptionString = ("Marcado Com Spam")

            ElseIf (rdr("Date_Bounce_SubType").ToString.Contains("NoEmail")) Or (rdr("Date_Bounce_SubType").ToString.Contains("INVALID_EMAIL")) Or (rdr("Date_Bounce_SubType").ToString.Contains("smtp;550 5.1.1")) Or (rdr("Date_Bounce_SubType").ToString.Contains("smtp;554")) Then
                errorDescriptionString = ("Direccion Erronea")
            Else
                errorDescriptionString = ("")
            End If



            Informacoes.Add(New info(ProgressString,
                                     StatusString,
                                     rdr("Mail").ToString(),
                                     rdr("Date_Delivery").ToString(),
                                     rdr("Date_Send").ToString(),
                                     rdr("Date_Reject").ToString(),
                                     rdr("Date_Open").ToString(),
                                     rdr("Date_First_Click").ToString(),
                                     rdr("Date_Last_Click").ToString(),
                                     rdr("Date_Bounce").ToString(),
                                     rdr("Date_Complaint").ToString(),
                                     rdr("Date_Delivery_Delay").ToString(),
                                     rdr("Date_Bounce_Type").ToString(),
                                     rdr("Date_Bounce_SubType").ToString(),
                                     errorDescriptionString))


            jobCounter += 1


        End While


        'jsonstring = jsonstring.TrimEnd(CChar(","))


    End Using

    Dim JsonGrande As New JobEmailSelected
    JsonGrande.draw = 1
    JsonGrande.recordsTotal = jobCounter
    JsonGrande.recordsFiltered = jobCounter
    JsonGrande.data = Informacoes




    Dim json As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
    json.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue


    Return json.Serialize(JsonGrande)


End Function
```

- Informacoes and JsonGrande are a model

Comment: You probably *don't* want to send 60,000 rows to the client. You want a table that allows interactive searching and filtering, and that displays matching rows via Ajax. See [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side).

Comment: That's IMHO a bad design decision. Why would you ever want to display **60k** records to a user? No one will ever wade thru all of them. Even the 1,000 you successfully pulled won't be consumed by any user. A better approach would be to  display the top x (best select criteria here) records and then let the user refine a filter. (Edit) Sniped by @Tomalak.

Comment: As others have said, put another way:  browsers aren't designed to handle this sort of data processing; they're designed for relatively-light-weight html.    Equally, *users* aren't designed for that to be of any use.  Add an *export to excel* option and let them filter/sort it there, which is designed for it.  Or better still, talk to your users to find out what reports / summaries they *actually* want.

Comment: I suggest you page the data you're sending to the client.  60k records is a lot.